# How to like a particular card in the list of ion-cards

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

how to perform "like" action on a particular  from a list of cards.

**.html**

```
<ion-content>
<ion-card *ngFor="let content of contents">

<ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="img/marty-avatar.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
    <p>November 5, 1955</p>
  </ion-item>

  <img src="img/advance-card-bttf.png">

  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Wait a minute. Wait a minute, Doc. Uhhh... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?! Whoa. This is heavy.</p>
  </ion-card-content>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
        <div>Likes</div>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        <div>4 Comments</div>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col center text-center>
      <ion-note>
        11h ago
      </ion-note>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

As the array contents has more than 1 items so the cards are generated more than  one , I want to like a particular card from the list of cards generated.How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register an event to `click` of the like button as following

```
...
<button (click)="likeCard(content)" ion-button icon-left clear small>
    <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
    <div>Likes</div>
</button>
...
```

Inside component file

```
export class SomeComponent {

    ...
    likeCard(content) {
        // do something with the content
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aditya

set this variable in **theme/variables.scss**

```
$colors:(
  ....,
  greydark:#717273,
)
```

**view file:**

```
<ion-col>
  <button icon-left ion-button clear small icon-only (click)="toggle()" color="{{colorCO}}">
    <ion-icon name="thumbs-up" ></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-col>
```

in **.ts** file

```
colorCO = 'greydark';
constructor(){}
  toggle(){
    if(this.colorCO == 'greydark'){
      this.colorCO = 'primary'
    }else{
      this.colorCO = 'greydark'
    }
  }
```

thanks